# SqlConnection not setting password when getting the ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am trying to save my connection string to a configuration file but the password is not being submitted.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={3};User ID={1};Password={2};",
           textBox_SqlServer.Text, textBox_Username.Text, textBox_Password.Text, comboBox_DatabaseName.Text)))
    {
      // test connection before continuing
      con.Open();
      configs.ApplicationConfiguration.SetConnectionString(con.ConnectionString);
    }
```

All is fine until `con.ConnectionString` and it does not include the password. What do I need to do to  So, naturally, when I go to retrieve it, the password is not there.

How do I get the password to set also?

Comment: code is fine , just break point and debug and see if Text has value at that point, mostly this happen due to `Postback` ,

Comment: When I hit con.ConnectionString the password isn't even in the string anymore... I guess it is stripping it out.

Comment: @ErocM, IT IS stripping it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ConnectionString is similar to an OLE DB connection string, but is
>   not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is
>   returned is the same as the user-set ConnectionString, minus security
>   information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false
>   (default). The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not
>   persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set
>   Persist Security Info to true.

From the MSDN documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perfect! I added `Persist Security Info=True;` and it gives me what I need. TYVM!